# UIView from CGRectMake does not have the right height

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I am adding a UIView to a container view programmatically, (the container view however is created in storyboard). Here is the code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController{
    @IBOutlet weak var dwView: UIView!
    private var dwSelector = dwSelectorView()
    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()
        addDWSelector()
    }

    func addDWSelector(){
        dwSelector.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
        dwSelector.frame = CGRectMake(self.dwView.bounds.origin.x, self.dwView.bounds.origin.y, self.dwView.bounds.width / 2.0, self.dwView.frame.height)
        println("dw height: \(self.dwView.frame.height)") 
        //prints 568, way too large of a value
        self.dwView.addSubview(dwSelector)
    }
}
```

The heigh of `dwView` is `123` in storyboard but the print state printed `568` and so now this is what it looks like:

[image: one]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should always not rely on `-(void)viewDidLoad` since view bounds is incorrect at this point or `- (void)viewWillAppear` if you are using auto layout to set your view's frame. If you layout view in UIViewController, `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` is a appropriate place, if you layout subviews in UIView,  it is `layoutSubviews()`.

Check this article to get more details:[Where to progmatically lay out views in iOS 5 (and handling orientation changes)](http://kevindew.me/post/18579273258/where-to-progmatically-lay-out-views-in-ios-5-and)

Comment: I did see that and put my code in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and everything works fine now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to call addDWSelector() in viewWillAppear()?

Comment: just did, same thing happened

Comment: I put in in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` and it works now